Access is Denied while running SQL bulk insert query
I am trying to run command Invoke-Sqlcmd via powershell using gma account and trying to insert into table through bulk insert.
Job is running on Windows server and SQL server is remote. Command provided is :
bulk insert TABLE FROM "\\Server\Drive$\FILENAME.csv" WITH (ROWS_PER_BATCH = 123, FIELDTERMINATOR = '|#|');
Error I am getting is

Cannot bulk load because the file "\Server\Drive$\FILENAME.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

What can we do to resolve this? Few article says to use the SQL Authentication rather than domain account, however we need to run the job using Task Scheduler on Windows server and need domain gma account to automate this.

Usually either permissions issue or the file is open or locked somehow.

Have you confirmed that the service account SQL Server is running under has access?

You may need to escape the $ with a backtick \`` to avoid it being counted as a variable in the query statement. e.g. "\Server\Drive`$\FILENAME.csv"`

@Hugo - Still same error

All the fancy accounts don't matter, sql server service account need to be able to access the file, which sounds unlikely if it's located remotely. You might have more luck running bcp.exe and friends in task scheduler to import the file since that is run on the originating server i think (albeit it will be slower)
